# Census data missing some .shp files

Tags: postgis, shapefile, tiger

I am following [this documentation from PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html).

For some of the files downloaded during the load process, I see errors like this

```
Unable to open tl_2022_04003_featnames.shp or tl_2022_04003_featnames.SHP.
Field tlid is an FTDouble with width 10 and precision 0
tl_2022_04003_featnames.dbf: shape (.shp) or index files (.shx) can not be opened, will just import attribute data.
```

When I manually download and inspect that actual archive,

https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2022/FEATNAMES/tl_2022_04003_featnames.zip

I see that it is missing .shp and .shx files. I notice this particular archive contains:

- tl_2022_04003_featnames.cpg
- tl_2022_04003_featnames.dbf
- tl_2022_04003_featnames.shp.ea.iso.xml
- tl_2022_04003_featnames.shp.iso.xml

but no .shp or .shx files

Other archives, for example files, do contain .shp files.

This one
https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2022/FACES/tl_2022_01001_faces.zip

for example contains

- tl_2022_01001_faces.cpg
- tl_2022_01001_faces.dbf
- tl_2022_01001_faces.prj
- tl_2022_01001_faces.shp
- tl_2022_01001_faces.shp.ea.iso.xml
- tl_2022_01001_faces.shp.iso.xml
- tl_2022_01001_faces.shx

Is that expected? I don't know enough about shapefiles and geographic information systems to know whether this is expected or a bug. Is there something unique about featnames that means they contain no shapefiles? Is it because feature names don't have any geometric vector data associated with them, so a shapefile would be pointless?

Comment: .shp, .shx, and .dbf are mandatory for all shapefiles.  If they are missing, it's invalid.